# Tasklist for remote machine and Findstr passing a exit code

Tags: batch-file, findstr, tasklist

I am trying to search for a process on a remote machine and pass an exit code so it can be handled by another process. So if the process exists output exit code 1, if not do nothing.
I wrote the script below with some help from another post. It works for a localmachine/local process but returns nothing for a remote process/machine. In the script below if i use the standalone tasklist command it works.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "cmd=tasklist.exe /NH /s RemoteMachine /u RemoteMachine\administrator /p Password /fi "Imagename eq Install.exe""

for /F "delims=*" %%p in ('!cmd! ^| findstr "Install.exe" ') do (
  echo exit 1
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to change the logic behind returning exit codes. Windows commands like `FINDSTR` use a different logic for that: if there's a match, the exit code is 0, and if there's no match, it's 1. And because the logic is already implemented in `FINDSTR`, you could just *use* it:

```
@tasklist.exe /NH /s RemoteMachine /u RemoteMachine\administrator /p Password /fi "Imagename eq Install.exe" | findstr "Install.exe" >nul
```

Comment: Thanks for your command. It works great. I tweaked it a little to give the output preffered to me.
@TASKLIST.exe /NH /s RemoteMachine /u RemoteMachine\administrator /p Password /fi "Imagename eq Install.exe" | FINDSTR "No Tasks"

IF %errorlevel% == 0 echo Exit 0
IF %errorlevel% == 1 echo Exit 1

Comment: Hey, that's a clever way of inverting the results!